# Auto-refreshing chat effiecently

Tags: php, refresh, chat

I have a chat that auto refreshes every 0.1 seconds but sometimes It takes forever to refresh and even load in the first place.

**Codes:**

I have my Body OnLoad script before the htdocs thing of html document.

```
<body onload="chat_load()">
```

This is my java script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var updateTime = 1;
var running = false;

var counter = 0;

function chat_update(){
    if(counter = updateTime)
        chat_load();
    else
        counter ++;

    if (running == true)
        setTimeout("chat_update", 100);
}

function chat_load(){
    $.post('chat_submit.php', {stage:"load"}, function(data){
        $('#chatbox #primary #window').html( data );
        counter = 0;
        setTimeout("chat_load();", 100*updateTime);

    });
}

function chat_send(){
    var text = document.getElementById("chat_text").value;

        document.getElementById("chat_text").value = '';
    $.post('chat_submit.php', {stage:"send", text:text}, function(data){

        if(data == "good")
            chat_load();
        else
            alert("Please enter a message.");


    });

}
</script>
```

chat_submit.php

```
if($stage == "load"){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat_chats ORDER BY time DESC");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $user1 = $row['user'];
        $date = $row['time'];
        $content = $row['text'];

        if($user == $user1){
            $num = 2;
        }else{
            $num = 1;
        }


        echo '<div class="list'.$num.'">';
            echo '<b>'.$user1.'</b> <font color="red"><i>'.$date.'</i></font> <br> '.$content;
        echo "</div>";



    }
}
else
    echo "No messages found be the first.";

}
```

**

> The problem I have is that sometimes it doesn't refresh or even load
>   at the first page load. Does anyone know why? I would still like it to
>   auto refresh quite fast but right now it seems to lag and fail quite a
>   lot. Are there any errors in the code or is there a better function I
>   can use?

**

Thanks.

Comment: You may take a look at websocket which are driver by events on onmessage events. (if you are targeting recent browsers that supports websockets).

Comment: Id is uniqe so $('#chatbox #primary #window') if overkill. $('#window') is enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499/ajax-polling)

Comment: Does your browser detect any java script errors? Also go to "chat_submit.php" to see if the php outputs the chat as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your Javascript code in

```
$(function() {
   // code here
});
```

which is a jQuery shorthand for [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready). And I'd remove the `<body onload="chat_load()">` and call `chat_load()` at the end of the Javascript.

Comment: How do I call chat_load() Googled it but could not find anything. Also what is the difference? I still can't seem to find any difference to speed. How do I use websockets as suggested by @Mehdi Karamosly ?

Comment: Just call it right after its own definition for instance. If it didn't solve anything, you can keep your code as it is. There might not be any actual difference, I was just suggesting a more standard way of doing it which is always better to avoid edge cases bugs. Websockets is a whole other story, it's another way (more efficient) of doing what you are trying to do but you need other tools server-side to get going, it's not a qucik change that you can make in 5min, it's about redesign the logic of your app

Answer (score 1):

At first 0.1 s interval for ajax pulling refresh is definitely too small.

I would increase it to couple of seconds.

And add some marker of last message so you could pull only latest massages and apend them to your chat messages so you dont` have to send all messages on every request, only new from last pull. This should lower mysql load and speed up data sending.

Comment: I increased it to 3 seconds and it seems much better. Thanks